# Easy Problems for Children to Solve in Python

Tags: python

I'm going to be teaching some year 9 and 10 students Python soon and thought it would be cool to do some Project Euler type challenges with them. The first problem seems doable by them, but I think some of the others may be a bit over their head, or not require enough programming.

If anyone has a place to find some easy programming problems, or can think of any, can they please let me know.

edit: By year 9 and 10 I mean that they have been in school for 9 or 10 years. So about 13, 14, and 15 type age. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Some of these are quite fun http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapters/

Comment: I hate to say this, but I think almost all programming problems are over the heads of 9-10 year olds.

Comment: @nightcracker: This sounds like the opinion 50 years ago that foreign languages should be taught to adults, as it over the heads of 9-10 years old. Now you start teaching languages in pre-school, as it is over the head of anybody old than 10 years...

Comment: try http://www.checkio.org

Answer (score 2):

Oh I remember something I was taught in school! My IT teacher created a class in python which attributes created a mathematical sequence. The goal was to guess the formula behind this sequence using only python. Obviously, you couldn't look at the file with class, only import it in python. Maybe there's more math than programming here, but to solve this, students will have to learn how variables, namespaces (to find the variables), loops (to print those variables), and classes (which store those variables) work in python and this is more or less everything you need to know at first, in my opinion.

Ah, good times. We also used to play "hide and seek" in shell on IT lessons: the teacher would hide a file somewhere and leave some clues scattered around, and we had to find that file using text environment on linux :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the right number :

The program chooses a random value betwen 1 an 100 then you have to guess.
It tells you if you are above or below.

Comment: Oh great idea! Will defiantly have that in the lesson somewhere. It's great because they can probably work it out themselves given the right starting point!

Answer (score 1):

My first scholar contact with programming really left a mark on me ;) The teacher provided us with a gui containing a sort of 2-d checkered board (let's pretend it was 20x20 cells). One of the cells contained a 'robot' and the programming interface basically exposed 3 methods: move forward, turn left, and check if the cell directly in front of the robot is a wall or open space. The game was then to 'program the robot' (teaching basic logic and loop constructs) to do all sorts of tasks like pass through every cell in the board. Later on, methods were added to the interface (to the original 3 methods) and 'objects' (not OOP, but .. other states the cells could occupy than just wall or empty) were added to the game. In the end the goals were for example for the robot to 'pick up' car parts and bring them to a 'car factory'. It was very nice IMHO to view programming as a game with 'scores' (least amount of cells required to achieve objective in this case) and I really promote Gamification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification in any school environment.

Cheers

Comment: Wow what a great idea! I'll have a go at creating something like that for them if I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how long you have to teach this, but [Udacity's cs101 class](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101) has some pretty cool problems and starts from a pretty simple level. The course is free, and you may find some of the problems useful stand alone if you don't have time for the whole thing.

Finally if you run out of ideas for meaningful projects that are easy enough / quick enough in Python or decide to find something easier for part of the class then consider using [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu), this is a fun visual programming language from MIT which allows you to use the constructs such as variables, loops, conditions etc. without worrying about syntax. This makes it nice and easy to create basic games / animations.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll have a look into those courses. Scratch is a great option but unfortunately our lessons have to be in Python. Will maybe see if we can use it in future years though!